# prototype methods do not visible in constructor if module load with require('moduleName')

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, require, commonjs

I have a simple module, it's code

```
    var Router = function(pattern) {
        this.setRoutePattern(pattern);
    };

    Router.prototype = {
        setRoutePattern: function(){
           this._pattern = pattern || "controller/action/id";
        }
    };

    module.exports.router = Router;
```

then in my other file I want to use router and have the following code:

```
var router = require('./../routing').router();
```

But this line of code fail with no method exception

```
Object #<Object> has no method 'setRoutePattern'
```

Why this happened, why prototype methods do not visible in constructor if I load code with `require` function?

Comment: Is the module going to export more than `Router`? It probably shouldn't ([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)), so you could just have `module.exports = Router;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to instantiate your class (so that it gets a `this` and its `prototype`).
To do that, you need the `new` keyword.

However, you can't combine that directly with require; otherwise, it will be parsed as

```
(new require('./../routing').router()
```

(calling `require()` as a constructor)

Instead, you need to wrap the entire function expression in parentheses:

```
new (require('./../routing').router)()
```

Or, better yet,

```
var Router = require('./../routing').router;
var router = new Router();
```

Comment: Dohh... what an idiot mistake. Too late for coding tonight. Thanks a lot.